# jQuery string to json object in MVC view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm passing a json string to my view as a String-model. I try to parse the string into a JSONobject. However it doesnt work,

My string is correct Json

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parseJSON(@Model);
```

However when i run it i get this, the parse seems to fail since i cant use my jsonobject. What am i doing wrong?

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parseJSON({&quot;elements&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;input&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Model is already a json string, you don't need to parse it. Razor also encodes html, so you need to prevent that from happening. Try this:

```
var jsonObject = @Html.Raw(Model);
```

Comment: doesn't work, dont get anything out of the jsonObject eventho the string is correct.

Comment: what does the generated source of the page look like?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing anything in a View is generally not a good idea. Views are to display data, not to process it, try avoiding logic as much as possible. Create a new Model class where one property holds the parsed object what you need, and do the parsing in the Controller. So the View will get that object and only display the results -- that is what it's used for.

BTW I thing the encoding is wrong, try this: `var jObj = JSON.parseJSON("{\"e\":\"value\"}");` because C# syntax is used in embedded code, not HTML.